# Tableau Server 9.2.4: Microsoft SSAS connection issue

Tags: tableau-api

I have built a workbook on my laptop connecting MS SSAS to Tableau server.  It worked fine by using MS SSAS connector.

After I published to Tableau server 9.2.4 and installed MS SSAS driver below, I got an error.

MS SQL SSAS 2014 driver on the Tableau servers. Microsoft Analysis Services 2012 SP1 64-bit (version 11.0.2100.60) from:  https://www.tableau.com/support/drivers

- An unexpected error occurred.  If you continue to receive this error,
  please contract your Tableau Server Administrator.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved.  It is a permission issue after reading the Tableau server log:

2016-03-21 16:17:23.968 -0700 catalina-exec-40 Default abc.com\John Doe ERROR requestId=VvCBA6BFEMwAABvo4hUAAAFx: wgsessionId=fu5qnq7cUm3ZAtpeZx6qqhmiOlTKCLW4 com.tableausoftware.controller.vizql.ExceptionController - Exception details:

Analysis Services database error 0x80004005: Either the user, ABC\TestSvc, does not have access to the Analysis database, or the database does not exist.
Unable to connect to the server. Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.

Errors occurred while trying to load the workbook "/views/Dashboard". The load was not able to complete successfully.